# Maven example to add extended agent

Tags: maven, open-telemetry, javaagents, maven-shade-plugin

I m writing my own extension with maven and I wanted to embed the extension and create a single jar. I saw an example in https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/extension/README.md#embed-extensions-in-the-opentelemetry-agent but this is in gradle. Does any one have an example for maven?

I tried with maven-shade-plugin, but I m not sure how to output opentelemetry-javaagent jar with the extension jar embedded inside

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by splitting my maven project in two modules:

- customization-lib
- javaagent

**customization-lib**

Put here your customization code. If you are using any dependencies which are not already part of the opentelemetry-javaagent you must embed them in your final JAR. Here shown with the `maven-shade-plugin` in your `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>customization-lib</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-samplers</artifactId>
        <version>1.32.0-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**javaagent**

This module will produce the JAR which is based on `opentelemetry-javaagent` but includes your `customization-lib` JAR in the `/extensions` directory. To do so, you can use the `maven-assembly-plugin` with a custom descriptor file (here: `assemble-javaagent.xml`):

First, configure your `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>javaagent</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>customization-lib</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry.javaagent</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-javaagent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>embed-customization-in-javaagent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>assemble-javaagent.xml</descriptors>
                        <mergeManifestMode>merge</mergeManifestMode>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

A few things to notice here:

- add your `customization-lib` and the `opentelemetry-javaagent` as a dependency
- use the `maven-assembly-plugin` and define:

  - `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` to use the output as your maven project artifact
  - `<mergeManifestMode>merge</mergeManifestMode>` to not override the `MANIFEST.MF` of the `opentelemetry-javaagent`

Then create a file `assemble-javaagent.xml` next to the `pom.xml`:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.2.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.2.0.xsd">
    <id>javaagent</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <!-- 1. Step: Unpack the opentelemetry-javaagent -->
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <includes>
                <include>io.opentelemetry.javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
        <!-- 2. Step: Copy our customization jar into the /extensions directory -->
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/extensions</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <includes>
                <include>org.example:customization-lib</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This is based on the `extendedAgent` task of their [build.gradle](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/extension/build.gradle) file.